# plotting vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How do I plot the following vector in Matlab? I have no clue how to deal with the problem. I have tested the plot function but it says that I have to define phi first, but then when I define phi the dimensions do not match and therefore I can not use  the plot function. Thanks in advance.

v = (cos(phi) sin(phi)) from 0 to 360

Comment: how do you define phi?

Comment: I did like this: phi = 0:pi/6:2*pi and v = [cos(phi) sin(phi)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to plot y=cos(phi) as a function of x=sin(phi). If so, then

```
phi = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
x = sin(phi);
y = cos(phi);

figure;
plot(x,y)
```

would do what you want. If you just want to plot both sin(phi) and cos(phi) as a function of phi, you would do

```
plot(phi,x);
hold all
plot(phi,y);
```

or, more compact:

```
plot(phi, [x(:) y(:)])
```

Where you create the two series as two columns in the second argument.

Comment: You're welcome. When Matlab complains about dimensions, use `size(x)` to find out the size of things. Using many small steps, rather than a big one, is also good for helping in understanding and spotting mistakes. Once you are comfortable with concatenation (using [x;y] for vertical, i.e. along first dimension and [x y] for horizontal, i.e. along second dimension), you can start building bigger expressions.